# my html to markdown wordpress plugin code using Parsedown doesn't work and ist possible to use regex

Tags: php, regex, wordpress

i made this code to convert my wordpress post to markdown and publish them to github he did publish them to github  but for som resion the convert didin t  work
markdown to use inside my wordpress plugin code